# Create Client Workspace using Perforce command-line on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, perforce

I am writing a script to build all our projects on a Ubuntu build machine.

Each project is stored in Perforce and I am using p4 to perform the above.

The command I am using is:

```
p4 -u <MyUsername> -P <MyPassword> client MyWorkspace
```

This runs and loads vim which I then need to perform a :wq [Enter] to quit from.

Can I auto-save or avoid vim loading?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this box is used via SSH from a remote location on our network.

Comment: I applaud the idea, but have you looked into using a continuous integration application?  Hudson and/or Jenkins is one we use, and it works fairly well with Perforce.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For my builds I have a text file, which I have in perforce, containing my client. That way I know what the client looked like at that build (I don't use a spec depot).

So on unix machines:

`$ cat client.txt | p4 client -i`

or for windows:

`type client.txt | p4 client -i`

creates the client from the txt file in perforce. You can create the text by doing a `p4 client -o <client_name> >client.txt` and change it from there.

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to try `p4 client -i`. From the help page:

> The -i flag reads a client specification from the standard input. The user's editor is not invoked.

So you construct your client-spec in a script and pass it to `p4 client -i`. Additionally, `-t` could be helpful, too:

> The -t flag constructs the client view by using the specified client's view and options as a template, instead of using the existing view or creating a new default view.

Answer (score 6):

I use heredocs to minimize the need for temporary files

```
export P4CLIENT=tmp_$$
p4 client -i <<HERE
Client: ${P4CLIENT}
Root: /tmp/${P4CLIENT}
Stream: //OurStreamDepot/${branch}
HERE
```

You only need to specify the `Client:`, `Root:` and `Stream:` fields (or `View:` if you are using the older //depot style)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a new client for each build. You can re-use the same client, just run 'p4 sync' to update the filesystem with the current version of the code to build.

Comment: I have been asked to do this by a colleague, and his requirement is to create then delete the client on each build. This may not be the best method (that discussion is for another time), but this was what I was asked to do. I will mention your suggestion and see what he says. I'm relatively new to p4 having moved from TFS.

Comment: Not sure about your case but we use TeamCity and any given build can be kicked off in parallel and built on any number of build agent machines including the same machine. The Root build directory is a long hash value that team city generates. I think P4 needs a constant value for the Root value of the client spec. In my type of case I think you would have to find out your hash value create a client use it and blast it so you don't accumulate thousands of useless client setups in P4.  This hash may be used again or never again so the only clean way is to create it, use it, and delete it.

Comment: The downside of creating and deleting a workspace with each build is that the full source code would need to be deleted and re-downloaded from P4 during each build. If an existing workspace was used, only the source delta  (changes) would need to be downloaded. For large code projects, this could be a significant performance hit for the P4 server, the build server, and network bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to keep using the same client, either set your variable `P4CLIENT=MyWorkspace` or use

`p4 -u <MyUsername> -P <MyPassword> -c MyWorkspace`.

Comment: I failed to mention that the requirement is to create the Client/Workspace and get everything for the build then delete the Client/Workspace so each time it is 100% clean.

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree with [Byran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355671/create-client-workspace-using-perforce-command-line-on-ubuntu/6358579#6358579). You do you need to create a unique client for every time you want to do a build. There is no issue with having multiple projects using the same workspace; you only need to have create multiple workspaces if you want to run builds in parallel on the same machine. Creating a new workspace and performing a full sync each build will *significantly* increase your build times.

If you need to ensure that you have a clean workspace configure your intermediate and output paths to point to a common location high up in the folder hierarchy.

```
Root
 /Bin
 /Intermediate
 /Source
```

This way you only need to delete those two directories and perform `p4 sync //filespec/` to do a clean build.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run the command 'p4 client' after 'p4 login'. It will ask for all the details after running the command. you just fill those details as per your requirement.

Mainly, You need to only focus on two parameters in the temp file. As soon as you save the file, the client would be created.

**Root**: This is the local repository path. for example,
**Root**: /User/codebase/code

**View**: stream you want to map to remote depot from your client. for example,
**View:**
//exp/main/... //expbuild_centos/...

```
[root@no1011142063123 ~]# p4 client "expbuild_centos"
Client expbuild_centos saved.
[root@no1011142036123 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the entire process inside perforce make a template workspace / client called `client_template` and pipe it in

```
p4 client -o -t client_template new_client|p4 client -i
```

Answer (score -1):

A different approach, assuming you are in the working directory of your client workspace:

```
echo "P4CLIENT=MyWorkspace" > .perforce
export P4EDITOR=true`
```

and then

```
p4 client
```

will either create the workspace if it is new one, or mention something like:

```
Client MyWorkspace not changed.
```

Comment: Setting P4EDITOR to true is just asking for trouble.